# Notepad++ blockwise code fold/unfold (recursive)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, code-folding

Is there a way to **fold/unfold a selected block of code** in notepad++?
I am aware of the shortcuts <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (Fold/unfold all), but this is not what I am looking for.

I usually start by folding all the code and then unfolding a particular method. In this scenario the individual fold/unfold shortcuts (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> OR <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>) does not come in handy, as it only works on the current (outermost) block, leaving the inner blocks folded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no keyboard command that I know of, but you can use the mouse. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on the `[+]` in the left margin, and Notepad++ will expand/unfold/uncollapse that block and all its subblocks.

Conversely, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click on a `[-]`, and it will fold/collapse that block and all its subblocks. Real intuitive, huh?